# Getting error "NameError: name 'ExceptionPexpect' is not defined" while using Pexpect in my Python scripts

Tags: python

I tried to run following piece of code on my server,

```
import pexpect
import pxssh
import getpass
s = pxssh.pxssh()
hostname = raw_input("hostname:" )
username = raw_input("Username:" )
password = getpass.getpass("password:" )
if not s.login('hostname', 'Username', 'password'):
      print ("SSH login failed")
      print str(s)

else:
      print ("You logged in successfully")
      s.sendline('uptime')
      s.prompt()
      print s.before
      s.exit()
```

But, Whenever I try to execute the code, I see following error message,

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "pexpect.py", line 1, in <module>
      import pexpect
   File "/export/rahul_lab/Python/pexpect.py", line 2, in <module>
      import pxssh
   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pxssh.py", line 14, in <module>
      class ExceptionPxssh(ExceptionPexpect):
      NameError: name 'ExceptionPexpect' is not defined
```

Can somebody guide, what is the issue here and why am I getting this error all the time?

Comment: At first glance, it looks like your `pxssh` and `pexpect` versions are incompatible. Which versions of each do you have, and how did you install them?

Comment: No, that's not the problem; your installed `pexpect` is being hidden by `/export/rahul_lab/Python/pexpect.py`. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have a `pexpect.py` file in your working directory. (Maybe even this very script?)

That hides the `pexpect` module that you've installed to your site-packages. Which `pxssh` needs.

The solution is to rename your `pexpect.py` file to something different. And check if there's a `pexpect.pyc` or `pexpect.pyo` left behind and, if so, delete those.

---

Of course I'm assuming you actually installed `pexpect` to your site-packages in the first place (with `sudo pip install pexpect` or `apt-get install python-pexpect` or whatever; the same way you installed `pxssh`). If not, you have to do that, too.